# Inequality with mathematical expectations

Tags: probability

Let a random variable $X \ge 0.$ How to prove the inequality $EX^4EX^8 \le EX^3EX^9$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p=\frac{6}{5}$ and $q=6$. Note that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, $X^4=X^{\frac{5}{2}}\cdot X^{\frac{3}{2}}$, $X^8=X^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot X^{\frac{15}{2}}$, $\frac{5p}{2}=\frac{q}{2}=3$ and $\frac{3q}{2}=\frac{15p}{2}=9$. Therefore, by [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), 
$$E X^4\le \left(E(X^{\frac{5}{2}})^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot \left(E(X^{\frac{3}{2}})^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}= \left(E X^3\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot\left(E X^9\right)^{\frac{1}{q}},\tag{1}$$ 
and
$$E X^8\le \left(E(X^{\frac{1}{2}})^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\cdot \left(E(X^{\frac{15}{2}})^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}= \left(E X^3\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\cdot\left(E X^9\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.\tag{2}$$ 
The conclusion follows from $(1)\times(2)$.

Comment: Where $X\ge 0$ is used above?

Comment: @user64494: $X\ge 0$ is implicitly used, because absolute values appear in Hölder's inequality.

Comment: I think when you write $X^{1/2}$.

Comment: @user64494: That is not essential. In fact, if $X$ is not nonnegative, the argument still works. You only need to replace $X$ with $|X|$, and then the right hand side should be changed to $E|X|^3\cdot E|X|^9$.

Comment: This is another cup of tea, is not so?

Comment: @user64494: This is essentially the same thing. I mean, if you do not assume $X\ge 0$, then you can replace $X$ with $|X|$ in each step, and finally you will obtain $EX^4EX^8 \le E|X|^3E|X|^9$. That is so say, to assume $X\ge 0$ is just to omit the absolute value symbol.